# tinyMCE editor problem with popups

Tags: javascript, popup, tinymce

I want to integrate tinyMCE editor in mys site and I have "installed" successfully in it. The editor is working fine but when someone who has kaspersky antivirus tries to upload a picture or preview the post message, the popups appear without borders and close button :(.

I have installed kaspersky to replicate the problem and see if I can fix it and it apears to be from the banner blocker, if I disable it the popups work just fine.
Although the demo version from the tinyMCE site is working without a problem and I have one installed on another site but its a joomla module and it's working too.

What could be the problem?

Thank you!

EDIT:Yes :( and I have the same problem, I have noticed something although, in the popup's html source generated when I open a popup :), it seems that the demo version has this html: 
`<div id="mce_4" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mce_4_title" class="clearlooks2" style="width: 490px; height: 414px; top: 152px; left: 351px; overflow: auto; z-index: 300010;" aria-hidden="false">`

and mine has :

```
<div id="mce_13" class="clearlooks2" style="width: 490px; height: 414px; top: 677px; left: 409px; overflow: auto; z-index: 300016;">
```

It's a little bit strange..

Comment: Somebody told me that I could use the inlinepopup plugin to solve my problems but the bad thing is that I used that plugin from the begging as the demo comes with that option :(. So no success so far...

Comment: did you choose dialog_type: "modal", ?

Comment: I have edited my post with some updates, please read it, maybe this can help you :(, Thank you!

Comment: hmm, i am using Kapersky and have no problem using the modal dialog

Comment: weird.. you have the banner blocker function enabled? If yes then what is your js configuration ? If I can ask :D. Thanks!

Comment: I have tested even the example that comes with the distribution packet but no luck

Comment: oh, i have the banner blocker not enabled